# How to do Angular error handling with Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, observable

```
let mydata = [a,b,c,d,1,2,3]
let MissingData = "No data available"

  public getData(): Observable<any[]> {

    if (this.mydata !== undefined) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next(this.mydata);
      observer.complete();
   
    });
  }
  else if (this.mydata === undefined){
   return new Observable(MissingData) 
  }
```

And then i call the data out of service so if there is any data log it and if there is no data return MissingData

```
service.getData().subscribe((res) => {
 console.log (res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of    `return new Observable(MissingData)`  I am returning `return throwError(MissingData);`

```
import { Observable, of, throwError } from "rxjs";

// let mydata = undefined;
let mydata = [1];
let MissingData = "No data available";

function getData(): Observable<any> {
  if (mydata !== undefined) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next(mydata);
      observer.complete();
    });
  } else if (mydata === undefined) {
    return throwError(MissingData);
  }
}

getData().subscribe((res) => {
 console.log ('data:', res);
}, err => {
  console.log('err:', err)
})
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rkarwj?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Comment: in your method if the array is left empty then it returns empty data:[] not the ```MissingData``` message ?

Comment: yes, sure, because empty array it is valid data, but if you want you can add a condition to check if the array is empty

Comment: we are checking only if the variable is not undefined: `mydata !== undefined`

Comment: i am also trying  ```if (mydata && mydata.length > 0)```  if this is true it returns data but if i do ```else if (this.VitalSigns.length <0)```  it returns no result ?

Comment: what is VitalSigns? you can write simply: `if (mydata && mydata.length > 0) { observer.next(mydata); } else {throwError(MissingData) }`

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: yes this solution works here fine with that array of mydata but for some reason i only get error message if there is no data. the array of data i have returns no result even if it's not empty.

Comment: it is strange. Could you create codesnippet somewhere in stackblithz?

Comment: basically if we  look on your array `let mydata = [a,b,c,d,1,2,3]` - a, b, c it is variables, but not a strings, you should use quotes ['a', 'b']

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an **Observable Error** manually like this.

```
  else if (this.mydata === undefined){
   throw Observable.throw(MissingData)
  }
```

And then subscribe for it like this

```
service.getData().subscribe((res) => {
 console.log (res);
}, err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

So the full piece of code would look something like this:

```
let mydata = [a,b,c,d,1,2,3]
let MissingData = "No data available"

  public getData(): Observable<any[]> {

    if (mydata) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next(mydata);
      observer.complete();
   
    });
  }
   throw Observable.throw(MissingData)
}

//Somewhere in the scripts
service.getData().subscribe((res) => {
     console.log (res);
    }, err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
```

Also I did a bit of refactoring just to shorten a code a bit. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

try to use promises. I put an example code for you here.

```
let mydata = [a,b,c,d,1,2,3]
let MissingData = "No data available"

public getData(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    if (this.mydata !== undefined) {  resolve(mydata); }
    else if (this.mydata === undefined){ reject(MissingData)}
} );
}


getData().then(
resolve => {
// succcess
},
reject =>{
// rejected.
});
```